# For a Google Chrome extension, how do I define a stylesheet toggle within the Popup?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, toggle

When a user clicks on the browser icon for the extension, it brings up the Popup that has been defined.

I need to create a toggle button to turn on/off a stylesheet for a specific page/domain when a user clicks a button that is **within** the popup.

For example, when a user uses the Adblock extension, when the user clicks the browser icon, it brings up the popup, which has a series of links. One such link is "don't run on this page", which then changes to "enable" which the user can click to turn it back on.

Another example (much better example): Classic Popup blocker has a button on the popup that says "add this page to blacklist" and once clicked changes to "remove from blacklist".

The classic popup blocker is generally the functionality I want for my extension (it's not doing anything with ads or popup blocking, that was just an example), so that when a user clicks the button on the popup it will turn a stylesheet on or off that I have written and saved as a .css file in the extension.

I hope I have made this clear enough to understand.

---

**SCREENS**

Here is a photoshopped picture that I made so that you can see exactly what I am trying to do:

[image: photoshopped screenshot toggle on]

---

and photoshopped again to see what should happen once you click the buttons:

[image: photoshopped screenshot toggle off]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method to dynamically inject/remove CSS (requires the `tabs` permission in `manifest.json`):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:
    'document.documentElement.setAttribute("RWchooseStyle", "style1.css");'
}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'myscript.js'});
});
```

In `myscript.js`, detect whether you have already inserted CSS. If not, add a new `<style>` or `link` element, and assign an `id` to it. Otherwise, replace the style sheet.

**Example** of `myscript.js`:

```
var selectedStyle = document.documentElement.getAttribute('RWchooseStyle');
var id, link;
if (selectedStyle) {
    id = 'RW_style_' + selectedStyle.replace(/\W/g,'');   // Sanitize id
    // Remove previous sheet, if available.
    link = document.getElementById(id);
    if (link) {
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    }
}
if (id) {
    // Insert new sheet
    link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = chrome.extension.getURL(selectedStyle);
    link.id = id;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(link);
}

// Remove temporary attribute
document.documentElement.removeAttribute('RWChooseStyle');
```

In this example, the CSS files have to be defined in your extensions directory. Of course, you can also use `<style>` instead if `<link>`, and dynamically set the style's content.

**Note: Do not forget to add the style sheet to the [`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) section of the manifest file.**

Comment: I am going to try this. If it works, I will accept your answer! Thanks for the help!

Comment: how how do I make the link execute this when it is clicked? As in, what exactly do I put in the HTML on popup.html?

Comment: The first part of my answer is JavaScipt, and should be executed whenever you want to load `style1.css`. The second part of my answer is a standalone JavaScript file. Both should be included in the extension. My current example currently allows only one extension. Simply replace `'RW_someStyleElement'` with eg. `document.RWChooseStyle`.

Comment: How about this: `<INPUT TYPE="submit" onClick="chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'document.RWchooseStyle="style1.css";'});'">` of course change RWchooseStyle to a name of my liking. Correct?

Comment: Or what about this: `<a href="#"
onClick="chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'document.RWchooseStyle="style1.css";'});'">Turn on Stylesheet 1</a>`

Comment: I don't know where to put `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'myscript.js'});`

Comment: Or I think this one suits my needs better:  `<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button"
VALUE="Turn on Stylesheet 1"
onClick="chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'document.RWchooseStyle="style1.css";'});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'myscript.js'});">
</FORM>` -- is that correct?

Comment: @webaddict What is wrong? Have you already requested `tabs` [permissions at `manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions)? As for your current attempts... The quotes don't match. I recommend to put my code in a function, in the script tags, then call it. Eg. `<script>function poof(){chrome.exte..... };</script>`. Later, e.g: `<input type="button" onclick="poof()" .... >`.

Comment: when I click the button, nothing happens. yes, I defined tabs permissions. Also, for now I'll just write "Toggle Stylesheet" but I would like it to be able to have the button change to "turn off" if it is on. As far as defining the javascript then calling it, THanks! I should have done that. Now let me try...

Comment: alright, i did all you suggested but is still not working, nothing happens when I click the button.. let me post some progress screenshots in my question for you.

Comment: please look over the screenshots I posted to see if I have an error somewhere.

Comment: we're almost there, just a little more help please! I'll go over your answers on your page and will vote up good answers so bonus points for helping!

Comment: It does not stay on. And it doesn't turn off again. Just turns on. I need it to turn off also. can you send a chat request?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8741/discussion-between-webaddict-and-rob-w)

Comment: works, just not the way I needed it. Thanks for your help. I hope someone can help me get this working the correct way.