# How to dynamically modify the manifest file css file for Chrome Extension, or what is the correct way to toggle a stylesheet on/off?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, toggle, stylesheet

Branching off my [Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646999/for-a-google-chrome-extension-how-do-i-define-a-stylesheet-toggle-within-the-po), a user successfully got me to serve a stylesheet but that is the wrong way; it is not what I needed to do.

So I have come up with a more accurate question:

Basically, you can make an extension permanently modify a web page by defining a content script in manifest.json.

I need the ability to, on the click of a button within popup.html, toggle a stylesheet on or off.

The answer to my other question I linked to, only allows my to serve a stylesheet, but that is removed again as soon as the page is reloaded.

I want to basically set the option for the extension to permenantly turn on a stylesheet for a web page, or to turn it off, by clicking the toggle button located in the browser icon popup.html.

See the screenshot:

[image: popup screenshot]

---

---

I think what I need is for the button to **change a setting in the extension** which will either turn on or turn off a css **stylesheet content script**, or **swap with a different css stylesheet content script**.

I hope I have made this clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to re-invent the wheel?

Have a look at [Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe), a UserScript manager (originated from [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) for Firefox).

If you still want to continue development of such an extension, the following methods can be used, on top of the one I described in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647059/938089?for-a-google-chrome-extension-how-do-i-define-a-stylesheet-toggle-within-the-po):

1. [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) - Detect tab state changes (place this code in your [**background page**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)):

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:
          'document.documentElement.setAttribute("RWchooseStyle", "style1.css");'
       });
       // myscript.js defined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647059
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'myscript.js'});
   });
   ```
2. [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info) - For persistence (so that preferences can be "remembered" in your extension):
   `localStorage.getItem('name')` to retrieve preferences, `localStorage.setItem('name','value')` to set preferences.

   Only strings can be remembered, so [`string = JSON.stringify(some_variable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)  and [`original_variable = JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can be used in order to save numbers, arrays and other primitives.

Comment: Reinvent the wheel? No. I do not want Stylish. I am defining a stylesheet in a chrome extension for a specific page, that will update for everyone who has the extension. Not the purpose of stylish at all. p.s. yes, I use stylish a lot. Not the same purpose here. User will not be able to edit the CSS. In fact, they won't even know they are changing a stylesheet. I wrote "Toggle Stylesheet" for purposes of the question. That's not what the extension will say.

Comment: I don't understand how to use localstorage for this.

Comment: "That will update for everyone who has the extension". Remotely? I recommend to not build such an extension, unless you have a good knowledge of JavaScript. A small error will have a huge impact on the user's security. As for `localStorage`, I have provided full examples for it. *This time, I'm not going to write the full code for you, because I'm actually very busy. Sorry.*

Comment: no, not remotely. On click. I would not build an application to remotely update. Anyway I think that would be against chrome extension rules. So you can disregard your last comment.