# How do you use Chrome Extensions to change CSS of a web site?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to create an extension for personal and possibly personal friend usage as well that simply changes a few colors that are displayed on a website I visit. I use Reddit Enhancement Suite, which has options for 'Night mode' that completely changes the color appearance of Reddit.

I would like to know how to edit or inject CSS code to this website so that the colors used in the website are what I would like them to be when I view the page. Mind you, this is of course just in my browser or in another Chrome browser using my extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically modify the manifest file css file for Chrome Extension, or what is the correct way to toggle a stylesheet on/off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648140/how-to-dynamically-modify-the-manifest-file-css-file-for-chrome-extension-or-wh)

Answer (score 21):

You can do exactly as you said: you can inject a CSS file or code into the page.
[The easiest way is through the manifest (look at the CSS property).](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative)

You only need to complete your `manifest.json` in order for Chrome to know in which pages it has to insert your CSS file into.

If you want to decide programatically when to insert the CSS, [you can use `chrome.tabs.insertCSS()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS), where you can insert a CSS file or just the code as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an extension, you could also do it in a [user script](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts). Then you can simply use `GM_addStyle`, just like with Greasemonkey scripts. It's much simpler to write and more lightweight in terms of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are already extensions made for this. The one I use is called Stylish, which only modifies appearance using CSS3 only, and not html. There are other extensions as well, do some google searches and you will find a few more.