# How do i get a chrome extension to change css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been creating an extension that will change a website's (minds.com in my case) css to change the color. The user of the extension can pick what "theme" they want of orange blue and dark and each will change the website in a different way by "activating" different pieces of code. Since this extension is a bit complex i dont know where it broke and i've been looking for hours. I hope someone out there could help:

Here's what i have:

Manifest file:

```
      {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Minds Color Extension",
    "version": "1",
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.minds.com/*"], 
      "js": ["injectedjs.js"],
      "css" : ["injectedcss.css"]
    }
],
        "browser_action": {

          "default_icon": { 
            "19": "icon.png",
            "38": "icon.png"
          },
          "default_title": "Minds Notification page",
          "default_popup": "popup.html"

        }

      }
```

injectedjs.js:

```
// Var block
var blue = 0;
var orange = 0;
var dark = 0;

// Activation block
function activeBlue() {
blue = 1;
}
function activeOrange() {
orange = 1;
}
function activeDark() {
dark = 1;
}

// Resets var block
function reset() {
blue = 0;
orange = 0;
dark = 0;
}

//Changes Minds css (Runs theme)
function run() {
if (blue == 1) {
    // Runs code that will change minds to blue. 
document.getElementById("mdl-color--white").className = "mdl-color--blue";
} 
if (orange == 1) {
    // Runs code that will change minds to orange
document.getElementById("mdl-color--white").className = "mdl-color--orange";
} 
if (dark == 1) {
    // Runs code that will change minds to dark
document.getElementById("mdl-color--white").className = "mdl-color--grey";

} 
}
```

Note: I have checked that mdl-color--white and all the others exist. You can test it by using inspect element on minds.com or make your own version.

Popup.html:

```
<!--
<!doctype html>
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Minds status</title>
    <style>
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:10;
width: 250px;
}
   #blue {
    background-color: #337dff;
}
   #orange {
    background-color: #ff5733;
}
   #dark {
    background-color: #4a505b;
}
    button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 27px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
    <script src="injectedjs.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">
<h2> Pick a theme: </h2>
<a href="blue.html"><button type="button" id="blue" onclick="activeBlue(); run();">Blue</button></a>
<a href="orange.html"><button type="button" id="orange" onclick="activeOrange(); run();">Orange</button></a> 
<a href="dark.html"><button type="button" id="dark" onclick="activeDark(); run();">Dark</button></a>
<br />
<div id="footer">
<font size="1"> <a href="mailto:one.snapp8@gmail.com?Subject=Minds%20Support" target="_top">Contact us</a></font>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need other pages i can provide them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, check out this open source project https://github.com/karthikv/my-style

Maybe you can get some ideas.

And take a look at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951593/how-do-you-use-chrome-extensions-to-change-css-of-a-web-site

Comment: The reason why i cant just put in a css content script file is because of the multiple "themes". If it where just one i could do that.

Comment: Your `injectedjs.js` exists both in `content scripts` and `popup page`, while in content page, there is no event to trigger its method. And you just use inline scripts in your `popup.html`, which is not allowed by default. Besides, if you want user to do some action then reflect it in current web page, you would need to establish communication between them, since they are in different context. Take a deep look at official guides and it seems there are some basic concepts for chrome extension you're not aware currently, sorry.

Comment: im voting offtopic because the code has multiple conceptual issues and the answer is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Thank you, i'll look for them. If you could suggest some pages that'd be great.

Comment: @zigmandel I didnt realize i had more than one mistakes, sorry.  I can edit my question to fit the topic Haibara Ai mentioned or i could make a new one after closing this one. What do you suggest?

Comment: @user6333114, [official guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) is really helpful, [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) part would help you quickly know how to write an extension.

Comment: Is there any Chrome extension that can change the background color of stackoverflow to black and the font color to white?