# Having issues using puppeteer and jsdom to parse the HTML of a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, jsdom

I am currently trying to create a javascript program that will parse the HTML from a webpage and then take each HTML tag put it into array so I can further select it for processing.

I am using puppeteer and jsdom for this. I am using puppeteer to request the HTML page.evaluate() and then use jsdom for mapping over each DOM element and assigning it to the array.

However when I receive the HTML from page.evaluate() for some reason it will not work with jsdom; it just returns an empty array when I attempt to select the DOM iterate over it and then add each element as a string to an array.

I was hoping someone could give me some advice on this subject as I am not knowledgeable with these libraries.

Thanks.

Code -

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  async function scrape(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url); // URL is given by the "user" (your client-side application)

     const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
       return {
         html: document.documentElement.innerHTML,
       };
     });

    
    const doc = new JSDOM(pageData, { runScripts: "dangerously" });
    
    const arr = [...doc.window.document.body.children].map(
      (child) => child.innerHTML.toString()
    );

    console.log(arr);
    res.json({ message: arr });
  }
  scrape("https://books.toscrape.com/");
});
console.log("test");
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 8000.`);
});
```

Comment: Puppeteer already lets you select and manipulate the live webpage. What's the point in serializing it, then passing it to a [totally separate HTML parser](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer) designed to simulate a browser? You have the real thing already--query that and skip the confusing step of passing a string to an extra library! A step further: last I checked, books.toscrape is totally static, so you don't even need Puppeteer or JSDOM, just a simple HTTP request and Cheerio. What data are you trying to get here in any case?

Comment: Hi ggorlen! I am trying to get the HTML of a website so I can receive each element. Then I need to determine which element is the largest on the page with width/height and is currently visible (through z-index). Then once I determine this I am going to inject inline css into that element to change the style of the element in real time. This is so I can create a custom program that will allow people to change the color/styling of any website they go to automatically with preset settings.

Comment: Why do you want to do all of this with Puppeteer? Why not a userscript or browser extension? Keep in mind, "I want to do X to any site" is immensely difficult because every site is different, so it's very difficult to write a one-size-fits all solution. There are a good deal of misunderstandings in your code, so I suggest taking a further step back and explaining a bit more carefully what you're trying to do.

Comment: Fair enough ggorlen. Yes I know it sounds strange, but I think it would be a pretty cool chrome plugin once I am finished with it. I am using puppeteer because I looked it up and they said to use this library. I am not extremely familiar with all of the libraries and which one is the most optimal so this is why I just chose one of them.

Comment: The problem with Puppeteer is it has nothing to do with what the user sees on a website. It runs on your server. Are you planning on returning the modified HTML, or a screenshot of the site or something? It'd be much easier, I'd think, to use an extension to manipulate the user's DOM directly, rather than sending the site off to a server, then through Puppeteer, then back to the browser, which sounds extremely Rube Goldbergian, unless you have a good reason for using this process.

Comment: Yes I plan on returning a modified HTML of the site. I want to be able to modify the html on the client-side similar to this chrome plugin : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/midnight-lizard/pbnndmlekkboofhnbonilimejonapojg

Comment: If you want to modify the HTML on the client side, skip the server and Puppeteer and modify it directly using the page script of your extension. Using a server and Puppeteer is very likely the wrong plan entirely--it's like flying to another country to buy a cup of tea when there's a cafe right down the street.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the advice. Do you have any resources where I could learn how to do this? I am utilizing reactJS to make this chrome plugin. So that is why I needed some sort of way to request the HTML from the website and then redirect it to reactJS. That is why I decided to use puppeteer. But if you have a better solution I like to learn new stuff so i'm here to listen.

Comment: Chrome extensions can manipulate the web page directly with plain old DOM selectors, either from the popup or content scripts. There are many existing threads, like [Modify HTML of loaded pages using chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068879/modify-html-of-loaded-pages-using-chrome-extensions), [How do you use Chrome Extensions to change CSS of a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951593/how-do-you-use-chrome-extensions-to-change-css-of-a-web-site), etc