# How do I set an option for a chrome extension style sheet to be permanently disabled/enabled?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, toggle

I found this other question which kind of answers but doesn't. I pretty want to do the same thing.

But the answer to that question does not **permanently** change the stylesheet, because on page reload, the stylesheet is reverted and nothing is changed.

[For a Google Chrome extension, how do I define a stylesheet toggle within the Popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646999/for-a-google-chrome-extension-how-do-i-define-a-stylesheet-toggle-within-the-po)

> When a user clicks on the browser icon for the extension, it brings up
>   the Popup that has been defined.
>
> I need to create a toggle button to turn on/off a stylesheet for a
>   specific page/domain when a user clicks a button that is within the
>   popup.
>
> For example, when a user uses the Adblock extension, when the user
>   clicks the browser icon, it brings up the popup, which has a series of
>   links. One such link is "don't run on this page", which then changes
>   to "enable" which the user can click to turn it back on.
>
> Another example (much better example): Classic Popup blocker has a
>   button on the popup that says "add this page to blacklist" and once
>   clicked changes to "remove from blacklist".
>
> image1 i.stack.imgur.com/92gVx.jpg
>
> image2 i.stack.imgur.com/Xvyyp.jpg

Here is what I currently have in the HTML file. In this way there is a simple checkbox, which if it is checked it runs the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#button").click(function(){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({ msg: "toggle" });
    });
</script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="button" /> TOGGLE IT
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of injecting it based on user interaction, you could do it based on a toggle of sorts. Just add a listener for the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event and filter it for the websites that you want to be affected, then inject the css if your toggle is set to true. For example:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  //assuming `cssToggle` is defined
  if(tab.url && cssToggle == "true"){
    // assuming `url` is the url you want to change
    if(tab.url.indexOf(url) >-1)
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {file:"style.css", runAt: "document_start"});
  }
});
```

An example of using an options page to toggle a stylesheet:

**manifest.json**

```
"options_page": "options.html",
```

**options.html**

```
<script src="options.js"></script>
[...]
<select id="cssSelect">
  <option value="true">Enabled</option>
  <option value="false">Disabled</option>
</select>
```

**options.js**

```
$('#cssSelect').change(function(){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'setCSS', css:$(this).val()});
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.method == 'setCSS')
    cssToggle = message.css;
});
```

Forgive the jQuery, that is what I use and I don't want to convert it to pure JS and give you incorrect code. So I define an options page in the manifest and on that options page I have a select with enable/disable options. When it is changed, I send the new value to my background page and update the `cssToggle` var accordingly. Take note that I am now testing against a string because that is what I sent in the message and it just makes for less code.

As far as having multiple style toggles. If it is just a few then you can just have multiples of this, but if it is more than that I would suggest doing something a little different. Maybe defining it as an array of objects with the url, toggle, and the file to inject like this:

```
[{url:url1,toggle:toggle1,file:file1},{url:url2, toggle:toggle2, file:file2},...]
```

Comment: Ok; what file would I add this into? `background.js` perhaps? Also, what exactly would `cssToggle` be like? Could you give an example (even using code from the other question)?

Comment: @user2284052 Yes, this goes in the `background.js` file. `cssToggle` is just a simple boolean and can be changed however you want. For example, you could use a `select` on your options page to enable/disable the stylesheet and have that change be propagated to `cssToggle` using message passing.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful; however, a little out of my knowledge base with regard to `message passing`... (Although I know what select is and a boolean (if statement etc.)). Can you give an example? Because I'm not sure about what message passing means. Here is what I have in my html file: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function(){
   chrome.extension.sendRequest({ msg: "toggle" });
   });
  </script>
     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="button" /> TOGGLE IT`

Comment: Additionally, in your current example, would this mean: no stylesheet is defined, if `!=`, but `style.css` is defined if `==`? Is there a way to define a second stylesheet `style2.css` if `!=`, and the original stylesheet `style.css` if `==`?

Comment: @user2284052 I updated my answer with an example, and yes you could just add an else for the toggle `if` and inject a different `css` file there. Also, you can't have any inline code in your html files, so move it all to an external file and include it like I did for the options page.

Comment: ok I am working on it, thank you for the excellent answer! Will be back shortly...

Comment: Ok when I change the option, nothing happens.

Comment: I've been trying many things but nothing works. Nothing happens when I change the option.

Comment: @user2284052 You have to include jQuery too if you plan on using it.

Comment: Jquery is included. Nothing happens. Option is not saved, nothing changes whatsoever. *(separate note: the uncaught exception error was fixed by placing the jquery call first)*